# VBA macro Enforcing specific input in a cell with a regular expression

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, regex

I need to restrict the user when he tries to input some string in a cell, this input to be restricted to the following list:      **C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, C10** ; words:    **merge,complete framed,width,border left,border right** and integers from **1 to 100** for example:
  C6 merge 1, C4 merge 1  . No other values are allowed except these.

I still can`t find out the exact regex which must be used to include all the rules above. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Dim strPattern As String
Dim regEx As RegExp
Dim vValues As Variant
Dim vValue As Variant
Dim strInput As String
Dim currCell As Range
Dim MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BY Blocks").Range("G3:G308")
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then
    strPattern = "the needed regex"
     'strPattern = "\b(C(?:10|[1-9])),(merge|complete framed|width),(\d+)"

    Set regEx = New RegExp

    vValues = Split(Target, ",")

    With regEx
     'For Each currCell In MyRange
           'If strPattern <> vbNullString Then
       ' strInput = currCell.Value
        'End If
              'Next currCell
        For Each vValue In vValues
            .Global = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern

            If .Test(Trim(vValue)) Then
                MsgBox "Match found in " & Target.Value & " : " & Trim(vValue)
            Else
                MsgBox "No match"
            End If
     If (regEx.Execute(strInput)) Then
     '"smth when the pattern is matched"
     End If

     End With
     Set regEx = Nothing
     End If
      End Sub
```

Actually the string pattern is wrong because it doesn`t find a match in If .Test(Trim(vValue)) condition

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: This    "\b(C(?:10|[1-9])),(merge|complete framed|width),(\d+)" regex which I used doesn`t find the above matches, I think something must be changed in its syntax

Comment: Why don't you make a long, simbolic separated string like "dude|this|is|the|string" and use `instr` to check if the input is in there. As you only need to enforce a small quantity of inputs IMHO using regex is overkill for this.

Comment: Ye, but I want to do it more dynamically and include strings and numbers not a long string

Comment: Another thing on my mind is to use maybe an array of expressions and check every one of them

Comment: I agree with dmb,  why use regex to do this? Just parse to an array instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that does not use **Regex**.

In a standard module enter this *UDF()*

```
Public Function IsItGood(aWord As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim s As String
    s = "|"
    tmp = s & aWord & s
    patern = ""

    For i = 1 To 100
        patern = patern & s & i
    Next i
    For i = 1 To 10
        patern = patern & s & "C" & i
    Next i
    patern = patern & s & "merge|complete framed|width|border left|border right" & s

    If InStr(1, patern, tmp) > 0 Then
        IsItGood = True
    Else
        IsItGood = False
    End If

End Function
```

In the worksheet code area enter:

    <strike>Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim BigS As String
        If Intersect(Range("G:G"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        arr = Split(Target, " ")
        For Each a In arr
            If IsItGood(a) Then
            Else
                MsgBox Target.Address(0, 0) & vbCrLf & a & vbCrLf & "has bad stuff"
                Application.Undo
            End If
        Next a
    End Sub</strike>

The event code takes phrase input from column **G**.  It parses the phrase into words and make sure each word is a member of the pre-defined list.

**EDIT#1:**

The previous version of the event code allowed too many `UnDo`s.  Use this version instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim BigS As String

    If Intersect(Range("G:G"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    arr = Split(Target, " ")
    For Each a In arr
        If IsItGood(a) Then
        Else
            MsgBox Target.Address(0, 0) & vbCrLf & a & vbCrLf & "has bad stuff"
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Application.Undo
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next a
End Sub
```

1. it will only validate if a single cell is changed
2. it handles cell clearing better
3. it limits the number of error messages
4. it removes the infinite loop cause by undo

Comment: This code is ok but within the foreach loop the msgbox is repeated for each input and after multiple clicks it stops

Comment: and then the common error out of stack space

Comment: I see the first for loops the 100 integers and the second from C1 to C10 and the msgbox is repeated foreach splitted string.Is there a way to prevent the multiple msgboxes?

Comment: This "infinite loop" occurs if a second input is inserted in the cell

Comment: @user3701825 this code will handle inputs to one cell at a time.  If you try to input to several cells in column **G** simultaneously, it will fail.

Comment: @user3701825  See my **EDIT#1** it should solve the problems

Comment: Yes it`s ok now

Comment: @user3701825  let me know if any other problems arise.....I am going to save this code.........

Comment: Yes I have another question but it` on another topic, you can see it