# VBA How to keep a specific comma after string split

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to keep a comma after string split so when I input some data in the cell to be like- C1 width 2 ,-keep this comma C8 merge 2 and not like the current output-C1 width 2 C8 merge 2. So this is my code:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim BigS As String
Dim arr As Variant
Dim a As Variant


If Intersect(Range("G:G"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
arr = Split(Target, " ")
For Each a In arr
    If IsItGood(a) Then
    MsgBox (" In cell" + Target.Address(0, 0)) & vbCrLf & a & vbCrLf + "is ok"
    Else
        MsgBox (" In cell" + Target.Address(0, 0)) & vbCrLf & a & vbCrLf + "has invalid values"
        Application.Undo
    End If

    Next a
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

For now this split method ignores all commas but I want to keep every comma between the 3 set of strings- C1 width 2 "here to be the comma" C8 merge 2

Comment: We can do this by fixing *IsItGood()* to accept all commas.  Is this approach okay??

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: Tomorrow I will try to apply the same tactic to another column with different values, if I have problems I will post another question :)

Comment: I tried to add nother if but then the whole thing stopped working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference:

[Previous Question](https://superuser.com/questions/1326875/vba-macro-enforcing-specific-input-in-a-cell-with-a-regular-expression)

the *IsItGood()* code was:

```
Public Function IsItGood(aWord As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim s As String
    s = "|"
    tmp = s & aWord & s
    patern = ""

    For i = 1 To 100
        patern = patern & s & i
    Next i
    For i = 1 To 10
        patern = patern & s & "C" & i
    Next i
    patern = patern & s & "merge|complete framed|width|border left|border right" & s

    If InStr(1, patern, tmp) > 0 Then
        IsItGood = True
    Else
        IsItGood = False
    End If

End Function
```

To make it "comma-blind", change:

```
tmp = s & aWord & s
```

to:

```
tmp = Replace(s & aWord & s, ",", "")
```

**Whether or not there are commas, you still need a space character between the words in the input phrase.**